# Is there a way to split rows into groups based on certain values?

Tags: sql, grouping, window-functions

consider this table:

[image]

I want to divide these rows into groups based on their id and price values: as long as two rows have the same id and price **and are not divided by any other row** they belong to the same group, so I expect the output to be sorta like this:

[image]

I tried using window functions but with them I ended up with the last row having the same group as the first 3. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One method is to use `lag()` to detect changes and then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_price = price then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by id order by dt) as group_num
from (select t.*,
             lag(price) over (partition by id order by dt) as prev_price
      from t
     ) t
```